# I am having trouble saving my PHP data to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

My .php page is connected to mySql database successfully. It can see the table and pull from the tables but won't save data from the text-box in my php form to the database.

**config.php**

```
     <?php


    try{
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nolarec;port=3307","root","");
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
} catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
}

?>
```

**fball_event.php**

```
        <form method="post" action="fball_create.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true">
                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>New Event</legend>
                     Id:   <input type="text" name="id"/>   <br/>
                     Name: <input type="text" name="name"/> <br/>
                     Time: <input type="text" name="time"/> <br/>
                     Type: <input type="text" name="type"/> <br/>
                    </fieldset>
                    <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Create New Event" />
        </form>



            <?php 

            require_once('config.php');


            if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

                include ('config.php');



                $id = $_POST['id'];
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $time = $_POST['time'];
                $type = $_POST['type'];
                $results = $db->prepare ("INSERT INTO nolarec.fball_event (id, name, time, type) VALUES ('$id','$name','$time','$type')");




            }
            ?>
```

Comment: please read the manuals about PDO prepared statements. It's all in there. http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: You really aren't getting much out of prepared statements if you're just going to concatenate values into the SQL string anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into fixing my prepared statements. Is that the reason why my data is not making it to the database are is that just bad coding? @Fred-ii-

Comment: that is exactly it. and while you're learning, get to know one of the "tools" http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Well that and the fact you have not attempted to `->execute()` the prepared statement or fetch the result of the prepared and executed statement

Comment: btw, you shouldn't rely on `<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true">` to use with your conditional statement. Because it'll be considered as "always being set". Name your submit button instead. also check for `empty()`ness against your inputs.

Comment: The `->prepare` basically sends the query to the server where is gets compiled. Then when you execute it ( with any parameters bound or passed on the execute) it actually runs the query and creates a result set. You then have to `->fetch_???` all the result set or one row of the result set at a time, in order to see any of the row data

Comment: also, why are you doing `require_once('config.php');` and `include ('config.php');` for? use one.

Comment: What will naming my submit button do differently? @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should be using placeholders for your data inputs in the query, second of all you need to actually execute it, you've just prepared it.  Try:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$type = $_POST['type'];

$results = $db->prepare ("INSERT INTO nolarec.fball_event (id, name, time, type) VALUES (:id,:name,:time,:type)");

$results->bindValue(":id", $id);
$results->bindValue(":name", $name);
$results->bindValue(":time", $time);
$results->bindValue(":type", $type);
$results->execute();
```

Comment: take a second look at this `(':id',':name',':time',':type')` - Edit; ;-)

Comment: saw that as soon as I posted it lol, knew I wouldn't be able to change it before someone commented :) thanks though

Comment: yeah, just in case the OP saw that, and think it was proper syntax. All's well ;-)

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project, and definitely read that link the other people posted